# Regex in python to group files based on matching start and end of file name

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a bunch of jpg files with names like these:

```
1_fileid1_1.jpg
2_fileid1_1.jpg
1_fileid1_2.jpg
2_fileid1_2.jpg
...
1_fileidn_m.jpg
2_fileidn_m+1.jpg
```

The first number is from a sequence of 2 parts so part 1 of file with id fileid1 starts with 1_ and part 2 with 2_. The last number is the page because these are image files created from documents so the _1 is page 1, _2 is page 2 and so on. The pages could be any number but the parts are always just 2 for each page.

Now I want to read these files so that I can group them in a sequence maybe in a tuple or list so the sequences should look something like.

```
seq1 = (1_fileid1_1.jpg, 2_fileid1_1.jpg)
seq2 = (1_fileid1_2.jpg, 2_fileid1_2.jpg)
...
seqx = (1_fileidn_m.jpg, 2_fileidn_m.jpg)
```

Each page of each file is a different sequence.

Is there a simple way to do this in python? maybe using re.match? But how can I make sure that the two files in one sequence have the same ending, i.e. _1.jpg (including the .jpg is useful because then I could avoid other types of files in case there are).

Edit:
Rizman's solution works fine if the files are on separate lines. What if the files's names are all together on a list and together with the files' paths? Like this:

```
../path/to/file1/1_file1_1.jpg/path/to_file2/2_file1_1.jpg...
```

I tried modifying Rizwan's solution like this: https://regex101.com/r/HvzkwL/5/

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Updated as per the change in the op's post:

use this:

```
(.*?/\d+(_.*?\.jpg))(.*?/)(\d+)\2
```

and replace by this:

```
\($1,$3$4$2\)
```

[Updated Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HvzkwL/7/)

You can try this approach:

```
(\d+(_[^\.]+\.jpg))\n(\d+)\2
```

And replace by this:

```
($1,$3$2)
```

[Regex101Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HvzkwL/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was really helpful. Unfortunately I'm still having trouble with my specific implementation. Could you look at my edit above and see if you can figure it out? Thank you

Comment: @Atirag plz check now , I have updated the answer as per the change in your question, btw it's is Rizwan :)

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much Rizwan :)